# listing same content on diffrent pages in MODX

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am trying to add a small "3 box news segment". I wanted it, to be visible on multiple pages. Normally I would just use chunks but the thing is that I want to be able to modify "3 box segment" content and preferably with a ritch text. Any Ideas how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getResources to grab the content from 3 hidden resources this way you still keep your chunks for the segment layouts and your actual content is in the resources [which you can update with the rich text editor].

Comment: getResources is the way to go here

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getResources you could also use getResourceField to get the value of a field or template variable on for example the homepage. This allows one place to manage it, and you can just reference it with getResourceField when you want it to show elsewhere.